# JQuery select & reset (clear) date range in HTML Calendar

Tags: html, jquery, date, calendar, range

I use a HTML calendar in which you can select a date range. Unfortunately it is not possible to delete a selected range. My idea would be to solve this with even and odd:

1. First click (odd) select first day
2. Second click (even) select range
3. Third click (odd) delete all selects and select new first day
4. Fourth click (even) select new range
5. ...

I am glad about tips and help. I can't get any further on my own.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('td.day').click(function() {
    if ($("td.firstClick").length == 0) {
      $(this).addClass("firstClick");
    }
  });

  $('td.day').hover(function() {
    if ($("td.firstClick").length == 0) {
      $(this).addClass("selected");
      return;
    }
    
    $(this).addClass("secondClick");
    var tds = $('td.day');
    var firstClick = $(".firstClick");
    var firstClickIndex = tds.index(firstClick);
    var currentIndex = tds.index(this);
    tds.filter(function() {
      var idx = tds.index(this);
      return idx >= firstClickIndex && idx <= currentIndex;
    }).addClass("selected")
  }, function() {
    if ($("td.firstClick").length == 0) {
      $(this).removeClass("selected");
      return;
    }

    $(this).removeClass("secondClick");
    var tds = $('td.day');
    var firstClick = $(".firstClick");
    var firstClickIndex = tds.index(firstClick);
    var currentIndex = tds.index(this);
    tds.filter(function() {
      var idx = tds.index(this);
      return idx >= firstClickIndex && idx <= currentIndex;
    }).removeClass("selected")
  });

  $('table').on('click', 'td.secondClick', function() {
    $('.selected').addClass('reserved');
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table tr td {
  width: 14%;
}
table tr td:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.firstClick {
  background: green;
}
.selected {
  background: lightgreen;
}
.reserved {
  background: red !important;
}
.secondClick {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="7"><b>2016</b>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="7"><i>November</i>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>mon</th>
    <th>tue</th>
    <th>wed</th>
    <th>thu</th>
    <th>fri</th>
    <th>sat</th>
    <th>sun</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td class="day">1</td>
    <td class="day">2</td>
    <td class="day">3</td>
    <td class="day">4</td>
    <td class="day">5</td>
    <td class="day">6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="day">7</td>
    <td class="day">8</td>
    <td class="day">9</td>
    <td class="day">10</td>
    <td class="day">11</td>
    <td class="day">12</td>
    <td class="day">13</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="day">14</td>
    <td class="day">15</td>
    <td class="day">16</td>
    <td class="day">17</td>
    <td class="day">18</td>
    <td class="day">19</td>
    <td class="day">20</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="day">21</td>
    <td class="day">22</td>
    <td class="day">23</td>
    <td class="day">24</td>
    <td class="day">25</td>
    <td class="day">26</td>
    <td class="day">27</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="day">28</td>
    <td class="day">29</td>
    <td class="day">30</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove class `reserved`, `selected` and `secondClick` in td.day click function to remove range selected before

```
$('td.day').click(function() {
  if ($("td.firstClick").length == 0) {
    $('td.day').removeClass("reserved");
    $('td.day').removeClass("selected");
    $('td.day').removeClass("secondClick");
    $(this).addClass("firstClick");
  }
});
```

and in table td.secondClick click function remove class `firstClick` to reinit new firstClick

```
$('table').on('click', 'td.secondClick', function() {
  $('.selected').addClass('reserved');
  $('td.day').removeClass("firstClick");
});
```